# Generic method returning ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist, type-mismatch

I am trying to make a program that creates an ArrayList given the type as well as the values that will be put into the ArrayList. The input structure that we have to work with is "I 6 7 5 3 1 -1 2" with the I being the type Integer (or S for String, etc) and the first number (6) being how many values are in the ArrayList. I'm not sure how to instantiate the ArrayList.

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    String type = scan.next();
    int length = scan.nextInt();
    int counter = 0;

    if (type.equals("I")) {
        ArrayList<Integer> A = new ArrayList<Integer>;
    }
    else if (type.equals("S")) {
        ArrayList<String> A = new ArrayList<String>;
    }
    else if (type.equals("D")) {
        ArrayList<Double> A = new ArrayList<Double>;
    }
    else {
        System.out.println("Invalid type");
    }

    while (scan.hasNext() && counter<length) {
        String s1 = scan.next();
        A.add(s1);
        counter += 1;
    }

    System.out.print(A);
}

//Removes any duplicate values in the arraylist by checking each value after it
public static <E> ArrayList<E> removeDuplicates(ArrayList<E> list) {
    ArrayList<E> inArray = list;
    for (int i = 0; i<inArray.size(); i++) {
        for (int j = i+1; j<inArray.size(); j++) {
            if (inArray.get(i) == inArray.get(j)) {
                inArray.remove(j);
            }
        }
    }
    return inArray;
}

//Shuffles the contents of the array
public static <E> void shuffle(ArrayList<E> list) {
    E temp;
    int index;
    Random random = new Random();
    for (int i = list.size()-1; i > 0; i--) {
        index = random.nextInt(i + 1);
        temp = list.get(index);
        list.set(index, list.get(i));
        list.set(i, temp);
    }
    System.out.print(list);
    return;
}

//Returns the largest element in the given arraylist
public static <E extends Comparable<E>> E max(ArrayList<E> list) {
    E max = Collections.max(list);
    System.out.println(max);
    return max;
}
```

Comment: @Lashane Fix the problem then we can move on

Comment: Cast the return result `(ArrayList<E>)A`

Comment: Thanks @Pshemo, fixed that.

Comment: At run time, there is no distinction between the different varieties of `ArrayList`.  There is no need for any of this logic.  Just always return `new ArrayList<E>()`

Comment: This question looks like [X/Y problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Why do you think you need such method?

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem So I replace "return A" with "new ArrayList<E>()"? How does that tell it what kind of ArrayList it is?

Comment: [Magic](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/genTypeInference.html).  The compiler chooses the right type for wherever you're using it.

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem Thanks a lot, that fixed it! Do you know why it doesn't work if I leave out "return null" at the end? Is it because when there is an invalid type it doesn't know what to return?

Comment: If you leave out `return null` at the end of mhradek's solution,  you end up with a method that's declared to return something, but sometimes doesn't.  That's a compile error.  Seriously, though, don't use mhradek's solution.  Just write `return new ArrayList<E>();` in your method.

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem What's the difference between giving it a specific type like mhradek's and giving it a generic type like yours? Won't it be the same when it is  returned from the method?

Comment: `A.add(s1);` You can't do that. `A` is not defined within any accessible scope the statement is executed in. You only defined `A` inside other `if` statement, thus you won't be able to access it within your `while` loop.

Comment: And secondly, since `String s1 = scan.next();` is always reading a string your `ArrayList` is ultimately an `ArrayList<String>`

Comment: @EyuelDK How do I make it so the created ArrayList is in the scope of the main method? That's why I tried to pass it to another method to then pass it back, but I'm sure there's a more efficient way.

Comment: Yes, it will be exactly the same.  So why write 11 lines of pointless logic, when one single line will be exactly the same?

Comment: @JoshCorreia Define `A` the same place you defined `counter`, `length` and etc... Try this: `ArrayList A = new ArrayList();`. No generic type specified. Then, you `type` variable should determine how you read your data in the while loop. Here is a snippet. `if (type.equals("I")) { A.add(scan.nextInt()); ... } else if(type.equals("S")) { A.add(scan.next()); ... }`

Comment: @EyuelDK I can't believe I forgot about raw types. None of this would have happened if I had remembered that lol. Thanks so much. I fixed it by adding a while loop inside each of the "if" statements and adjusting it according to the type!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I cannot in good conscious give you the answer you want, but rather I'll give you the answer you need.

***DON'T DO THAT!***

It serves no purpose at all. Datatype erasure at compile time of generics makes the `ArrayList<Whatever>` act equivalently to `ArrayList<?>` You cannot ascertain the generic type during runtime unless you type check the elements within the `ArrayList`

You might as well write this code, it'll give you the same exact results:

```
public static ArrayList<?> returnProper(String type) {
    if(type.length() == 1 && "ISD".contains(type)) {
        return new ArrayList();
    } else {
        System.out.println("Invalid type");
        return null;
    }
}
```

***THUS, PLEASE DON'T DO THAT***

Comment: Are you saying that the entire method is useless, or the way it is coded?

Comment: @JoshCorreia The entire method is useless. It does nothing at all. I suggest you share with us the problem you are trying to solve because the solution you are attempting to implement does nothing at all.

Comment: I updated the post to try to make my question more clear.

Answer (score 1):

Replace the second E with an "?" and then fix the method to return.

```
public static <T> ArrayList<?> returnProper(String type) {
    if (type.equals("I")) {
        return new ArrayList<Integer>();
    } else if (type.equals("S")) {
        return new ArrayList<String>();
    } else if (type.equals("D")) {
        return new ArrayList<Double>();
    } else {
        System.out.println("Invalid type");
    }

    return null;
}
```

Comment: I receive the error "This method must return a result of type ArrayList<?>"

Comment: Even with the return null at the end?

Comment: @mradek Ah When I add the return null it works. Why doesn't it work without return null?

Comment: Why would you do this?  All of that logic is completely irrelevant after run time type erasure.  Code like this will not pass code review where I work.

Comment: @JoshCorreia Your code says "else, print this line" but still needs to return something as the method is defined as always returning something. If you do not want to ever return null I would consider throwing an exception and handling it. Though, as other have commented, this whole method may need some rework as it may not be necessary.

Comment: @mhradek How would I get the ArrayList back into my main method? ArrayList<?> A = returnProper(type);?

Comment: @JoshCorreia Brother, please listen to the comments. They are giving you words of wisdom but you are ignoring it to achieve a solution for a nonexistent problem.